# What exactly does the `dfbeta()` function do?

Tags: regression

I found the `dfbeta()` function in my regression diagnostics. What does this function exactly do?

Comment: Although a name of this kind could be used in various different programs, and the meaning is likely to be similar if not identical across software, it's always good practice to specify the software you're using. That's true even if at any instant the whole world uses R. On a different level: what does the documentation say?

Comment: I'm assuming this is R. Have you looked at `?dfbeta`?

Comment: There are many threads on this site containing the word dfbeta which you can find using the search facility at the top of the screen. Does any of them answer your question?

Answer (score 8):

You can find a description of DFBETA on the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Influential_observation. Reading the source code of the function is not trivial, but you can view it by typing `stats:::dfbeta.lm` at the command prompt (you need the `stats:::` because it is technically part of a package, and the `.lm` because it is a method of an S3 class).

What it does is actually quite simple; the ith row of the output of `dfbeta` gives the differences in the coefficients of the original regression versus the regressions you get from deleting the ith observation in your data set.

Here is how you can check this:

```
set.seed(20180208)

x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)

model <- lm(y~x)
dfbeta(model)

check <- matrix(rep(0,20), nrow=10)

for (i in 1:10){
  model_i <- lm(y~x, data=data.frame(x=x,y=y)[-i,])
  check[i,] <- coef(model) - coef(model_i)
}
```

(`dfbeta` actually outputs a data frame, but you can see that the values in `dfbeta(model)` and `check` are the same).

Edit: here is an illustration as well. A large DFBETA indicates an influential observation. Here, you can see that observation 9 is influential because the regression line changes quite dramatically when it is omitted. People also like to re-scale these to get what is called DFBETAS, which you can obtain from the `dfbetas` function.

```
set.seed(20180208)

x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)

model <- lm(y~x)
dfbeta(model)

check <- matrix(rep(0,20), nrow=10)

for (i in 1:10){
  assign(paste("model_", i, sep=""), lm(y~x, data=data.frame(x=x,y=y)[-i,]))
  check[i,] <- coef(model) - coef(get(paste("model_", i, sep="")))
}

#illustration

plot(x, y, pch=19, col=rgb(0,0,0,0.5))
abline(coef(model), lwd=2)

for (i in 1:10) text(x[i], y[i]+0.2, i)

for (i in 1:10) abline(coef(get(paste("model_", i, sep=""))), 
                       col=rgb(0,0,1,0.3),
                       lwd=5*sum((check^2)[i,])/max(rowSums(check^2)))
```

[image]